# Is there a more concise way to get attributes from a parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a self-referential User model for adding friends. I have a User model that `has_many :friend_requests`.  When a user adds a friend a record is created in the `friend_request` model which has the `user_id` and the `friend_id`.

I can list all the requested friend_ids from the `friend_request` model but I can't figure out how to easily turn those ids back into usernames without an ugly loop like this in the view:

```
  <% for user in @user.friend_requests %>
    <% @usr = User.where(id: user.friend_id) %>
    <% @usr.each do |usr| %>
      <%= usr.username %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This is the friend_request controller:

```
 def index
        @incoming = FriendRequest.where(friend: current_user)
        @outgoing = current_user.friend_requests
        @user = current_user
end
```

Is there a simpler way to get the user's name from the Users table without looping through all the friend_ids in the friend_request table

Comment: If you know you only get one result from `User.where(id: user.friend_id)` (which is a collection). You can use `find` or `find_by` instead. The difference is that `find` raises an error if an record can't be found, while `find_by` returns `nil`. `usr = User.find(user.friend_id)` or `usr = User.find_by(id: user.friend_id)`. Alternatively if you have set up the association correctly you can do `usr = user.friend`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in your given code the variable `user` is not what the name suggest, namely an instance of *FriendRequest*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a "has_many: through"

```
class Friends < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend_requests, class_name: 'User'
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :friends
  has_many :friend_requests, through: :friends
end


@user.friend_requests << @other_user
@other_user.friend_requests << @user

@user.friend_requests.delete @other_user
@other_user.friend_requests.delete @user
```

Answer (score 0):

It is code from one of my projects, I use Friendship instead of FriendRequest

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
  has_many :user_followers, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'friend_id', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :user_followers, source: :user
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end
```

In controller `@friends = current_user.friends`.
And then in view just two lines

```
<% @friends each do |user| %>
  <%= user.username %>
```

Comment: I think this works but from what I can tell it does not provide a temporary state where users can "request" a friend and see "friend requests".